# Postgresql foreign data wrapper

Tags: postgresql

hoping for some help as I am very new to postgresql admin!

I have 2 servers added to pgadmin, server 1 is a hosted db on Heroku the other is local to the server

I want to add the Heroku db as foreign tables to the local db

can I link these 2 servers? as so far I have failed

I have the fdw extension setup locally, and I am able to use it across three local dbs ok, do I need the extension also setup on the Heroku db?

I have setup the fdw server as 
host localhost              --- should this be the Heroku host path? or is this ok since I have added                                                      -                            --server local? I get fsrvoption error if I add actual host path
dbname dbname
port 5432

and then setup user 
user username
password password

any help appreciated!

mal

[image: error when I add path to host on external storage]

[image: when importing foreign schema]

Comment: "or is this ok since I have added - --server local?" Added it to what?  Please show the commands you ran.

Comment: " I get fsrvoption error"  Please show the actual error message.

Comment: I added the fdw server as local (despite it being hosted else where, under the assumption that I have created a local server connection to it)                                      CREATE SERVER herokudata
    FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER heroku
    OPTIONS (host 'localhost',dbname 'heroku',port '5432');

Comment: hi jjanes, I added a screen shot of the actual error, I get this when I change host from local host to actual path.compute.amazonaws.com, but I assume when I created the server local that I can say the host is localhost??

Comment: Your screen shot does not show a PostgreSQL error. It seems to come from the web app itself, maybe pgadmin4, or some heroku-specific management tool.

Comment: hi jjanes, yes this is the error I get in pgadmin if I enter web host address rather than use local host. I am assuming that I can use localhost as I have added the server to pgadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to set up anything on the remote server to access it via foreign data wrapper; the foreign data wrapper will access the remote database as a regular database client.

Once you hace set up postgres_fdw correctly, you can use it to access tables on the remote server just as if they were local tables. A foreign table is a bit like a view in some respects.

Maybe it helps to understand the objects involved:

- The *foreign data wrapper* encapsulates the code to access the remote data source (PostgreSQL client).
- The *foreign server* wraps the connect string for the remote database.
- The *user mapping* contains the credentials for a user to access the foreign server.
- The *foreign table* describes a table on the remote server.

You can use the command `IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA` to automatically define foreign tables for all (or part) of the tables in a schema on the remote server.

Once the foreign tables are defined correctly, you can use them in SQL statements just like local tables, but you will actually read and write data on the remote server.

After some debugging, the problem turned out to be this:

- Creating the foreign server using pgAdmin caused a strange error with `fsrvoption` (running `CREATE SERVER` via the query tool worked).
- Creating the foreign server with `localhost` rather than the correct server address unsurprisingly gave the error that the database doesn't exist.

Comment: hi laurenz, I think I have done this all! but when I try to import the foreign schema I get errors I use                                                                              create schema herokulive;
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public
    FROM SERVER herokudata INTO herokulive;                                                                    but I get the error                                                                                                            ERROR:  could not connect to server "herokudata"
DETAIL:  FATAL:  database "dbname" does not exist

Comment: Well, then you have the explanation. Choose a database that exists. Don't use upper case in database names (or other object names).

Comment: but it does exist :) I added screen shot showing the db

Comment: Please show the exact `CREATE SERVER` and `CREATE USER MAPPING` statements you used. Also, what is host name and port for the remote database? You may be connecting to the wrong PostgreSQL instance.

Comment: CREATE SERVER flowher
  FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
  OPTIONS (host 'localhost', dbname 'd11mcb7mgocbd9');
  
  
  CREATE USER MAPPING FOR CURRENT_USER
  SERVER flowher
  OPTIONS (user 'user1', password 'password');

Comment: can I use local host as hostname? I am assuming I can because I have created the server on pgadmin??

Comment: Perhaps spaces in the database name? What do you get if you connect to the remote database and run `SELECT current_database(), current_database()::bytea;`?

Comment: I just get the dbname d11mcb7mgocbd9 d11mcb7mgocbd9

Comment: Perhaps it is a network configuration error. What does `localhost` resolve to?

Comment: just the server I have the local dbs, but I have also added the server connection to the hosted db as well. should I be using localhost for that or the actual host address? I have tried actual host address but I get an error 'fsrvoption' when I try to save the fdw server connection

Comment: If the database is on the remote host, you have to use that remote host for the foreign server definition, not `localhost`. Could you add the `CREATE SERVER` statement and the error message to the question?

Comment: I think I have it :) I was creating the server using pgadmin front end, but I just created the server using script and host name and I think I have my foreign table imported !!!! thanks so much for walking me through this laurenz